# Testing asp.net 5 vnext middleware from a TestServer

Tags: unit-testing, testing, asp.net-core

In owin, its possible to test a web api in unit test using a TestServer (see this [blog](http://www.juliencorioland.net/archives/using-owin-to-test-your-web-api-controllers#.VSe-OPmsWQA)).

Is this functionality available for asp.net 5 middleware ?

### UPDATE:

based on responses below, I tried to use *TestServer*, but visual studio complains that **'The type or namespace name 'AspNet' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you .....'**

- I use Visual Studio 2015
- in my nuget sources (settings) I have (https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/)
  (I also tried with https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/, but got the same problem)
- here is my project.json file

  ```
  {
      "version": "1.0.0-*",
      "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.AspNet.Http": "1.0.0-*",        
          "Microsoft.AspNet.TestHost":  "1.0.0-*",
          "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting":  "1.0.0-*", 
          "Microsoft.AspNet.Testing" :  "1.0.0-*",
          "xunit": "2.1.0-beta1-*",
          "xunit.runner.aspnet": "2.1.0-beta1-*",
          "Moq": "4.2.1312.1622",
          "Shouldly": "2.4.0"
      },
      "commands": {
          "test": "xunit.runner.aspnet"
      },
      "frameworks" : {
          "aspnet50" : {
              "dependencies": {
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: What makes you wonder about this? Even if you cannot do it, you can duplicate your app and have two identical prod servers, from which you will use one as your test server.

Comment: In fact what I would like is a inMemory test server, that runs during a unit test and then closes.

Comment: Yes, that would be like that, except that it does not disturb your prod application.

Comment: based on @tugberk answer, I created a [repo](https://github.com/CedricDumont/vnext-playground/tree/master/MultiTestServer) to use this feature

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is available on ASP.NET 5 as well: [Microsoft.AspNet.TestHost](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.TestHost).

Here is a sample. Middleware:

```
public class DummyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public DummyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DummyMiddleware");
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;

        await context.Response.WriteAsync("hello world");
    }
}
```

Test:

```
[Fact]
public async Task Should_give_200_Response()
{
    var server = TestServer.Create((app) => 
    {
        app.UseMiddleware<DummyMiddleware>();
    });

    using(server)
    {
        var response = await server.CreateClient().GetAsync("/");
        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

You can find more about the usage of the [TestServer](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.TestHost/TestServer.cs) class on [the tests](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/test/Microsoft.AspNet.TestHost.Tests/TestServerTests.cs).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you tell me which nuget source you are using ? because I tried to import these packeges in my project.json, but I cannot reference TestServer because when using Microsoft.AspNet.TestHost; visual studio complains that namespace AspNet does not exists. I will update my question so that you can look at my project.json.

Comment: @CedricDumont aspnetrelease feed has it: https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnetrelease

Comment: Hi @tugberk, in the same spirit I posted another question in this same spirit. If you have few minutes to look at, it would help me a lot : [using two testServer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29621267/using-asp-net-5-testserver-to-mock-an-external-api-call)